# FullSimplify exponential gives zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

```
gs[x_, h_, c_, w_] := h*Exp[-Log[2]*(x - c)^2/w^2];
gs[x, 0.343131084805, 118.276987081, 4.0035196987]
```

gives

```
0.343131 E^(-0.0432456 (-118.277 + x)^2)
```

However

```
FullSimplify[gs[x, 0.343131084805, 118.276987081, 4.0035196987]]
```

gives

```
0.
```

What is going on?

Comment: Seems like a bug. But `gs` is unnecessary  to reproduce the issue. This code is enough `0.343131 E^(-0.0432456 (-118.277 + x)^2) // FullSimplify`

Comment: `FullSimplify` and related functions apply various transformations. In presence of machine numbers and operations such as exponentiation one can get an underflow to zero. Which means these are not good functions to mix with machine reals.

Comment: `-118.277` into the exponential gives a very small number which probably gives underflow. If you use `Rationalize[...,0]` on your numbers you do not get `0` after the `FullSimplify`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: If there was an underflow but no message about it - it is still a bug.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I don’t disagree. There is a bug report in our database.

Answer (score 2):

I am on the side of a bug, although as @Daniel Lichtblau points out in the comment:

> In presence of machine numbers and operations such as exponentiation
> one can get an underflow to zero.

but no error message about underflow indicates it is a bug.

```
0.343131 E^(-0.0432456 (-118.277 + x)^2) // FullSimplify
0.343131 E^(-0.0432456 (-118.277 + x)^2) /. x -> 118.277 // FullSimplify
```

---

```
0.

0.343131
```

It is also interesting that using `ExpandAll` before `FullSimplify` the output does not reduce to `0.`.

```
0.343131 E^(-0.0432456 (-118.277 + x)^2) // ExpandAll // FullSimplify
```

---

```
6.23836*10^-264 E^((10.2299 - 0.0432456 x) x)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a numerical underflow, but unfortunately without a concomitant message. If you use software reals instead of machine reals, you get the right answer:

```
In[1]:= gs[x_, h_, c_, w_] := h*Exp[-Log[2]*(x - c)^2/w^2];

In[2]:= FullSimplify[
  gs[x, 0.343131084805`20, 118.276987081`20, 4.0035196987`20]] // InputForm

Out[2]//InputForm=
0.343131084805`20./E^(0.04324555963136047230860620803921907684`19.69897000433602*
   (-118.276987081`20. + x)^2)
```